# Have governments or combatants marked the houses of groups to be persecuted?

Tags: government, genocide

I came across a claim on [Skeptics](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/28450/has-the-us-government-tagged-people-to-be-killed-with-stickers-on-the-mailboxes) about marking the houses of those to be killed by the government.

The idea appeared to me as pretty silly - "Why would the government make it that obvious?", but I have a vague recollection that governments, or maybe combatants in an ugly civil war, have marked houses of people in the wrong ethnic or religious group. And it wasn't the drawing of yellow star of Davids on Jewish shops, either.

Have government or combatants engaged in this kind of behaviour?

Comment: As long as I know, marking opponents'homes would work primarily as a threat ("you are in our list, leave now or face the consequences"). Of course, that does not forbid that those who remain are later murdered. If your original intent was killing them, you do not give a public warning: you write a secret list and arrest them with as much secrecy as you can (so other people in your list do not realize too soon), or setup an all-out campaign because the enemy can't run away. Anyway, I have a hunch that maybe are thinking about the Rwandan genocide: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rwandan_Genocide

Comment: Of course the opposite story occurred; the Jews marked the doors of their houses with blood to avoid punishment by God.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a conspiracy theory.

Comment: @TomAu It is not a conspiracy theory, he asks *if* there are instances in history where marking of houses actually happened. We know that genocide and atrocities are often foreshadowed by ostracization and assaults, so marking of houses may actually happen.

Answer (score 2):

The story of marking the houses that you read probably referred to the St. Bartholomew's Day massacre, when the houses of [Huguenots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huguenot) were indeed marked
by crosses, according to some accounts. If I remember correctly this is also shown in the movie Intolerance by Griffith.

Comment: or it referred to the persecution of Jews in Nazi Germany where people would paint signs and slogans on houses and businesses owned by Jews as a "warning" to people that there were Jews in the area. This was however not the government doing it (though they encouraged it).

Comment: @jwenting, the marking of Jewish homes and shops was government policy for Nazi standards of government -- they made a mess out of state and party chains of command.

Comment: @o.m. it became such, but started as a more or less spontaneous campaign. Probably launched by party officials of course (most German nationals were members of the party and a lot of them held some function within it, even if only as a minor informant), but without a command from up high.

Comment: @jwenting, it was started by SA and SS, hardly average party members, and fanned by the party-controlled press. The party had something like 5 million members prior to the war, which isn't "most German nationals" (but more were in supporting organizations).